# Java equivalent to C# using alias

Tags: c#, java

Is there a Java equivalent to the C# using keyword, as used in the following example?

```
namespace TheirNamespace
{
    public class ContestedClassName
    {
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ContestedClassName
    {
    }
}

namespace MyBoundaryNamespace
{
    using MyRenamedClass = MyNamespace.ContestedClassName;
    using TheirRenamedClass = TheirNamespace.ContestedClassName;

    public class Translator
    {
        public TheirRenamedClass Translate(MyRenamedClass value)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that can't be done in Java, you need to use fully qualified classnames in that case.

E.g.

```
public TheirNamespace.ContestedClassName translate(MyNamespace.ContestedClassName value) {
}
```

Comment: ooh...forgot about `translate`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no - if you're using two classes w/ the same name, you have to explicitly reference them by the namespace:

```
MyNamespace.ContestedClassName MyRenamedClass = new MyNamespace.ContestedClassName();
TheirNamespace.ContestedClassName TheirRenamedClass = new TheirNamespace.ContestedClassName();
```

Comment: You can import one and then only need to use the fully qualified name for the other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe no. You would have to use the complete package name:

`ContestedClass c = com.somewhere.mypackage.ContestedClass`
`ContestedClass c2 = com.somewhere.else.ContestedClass`

Answer (score -2):

Java 7 introduced try-with-resources which is the functional equivalent of C#'s using.  Details can be found [here](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/08/java-7-try-with-resources-statement)

Quick example:

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) 
{ 
    String line; 
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
       myList.add(line); 
    } 
 }

catch (IOException e) 
{ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}

Comment: He's taking about the `using` in C# in the context of defining the imported namespaces, not the `using` for disposing of disposable resources.